# Custom Post Type for Shortcode Use - Prevent it display as a post (with slug)

Tags: custom-post-types, shortcode, slug

I've developed a series of plugins which can display categorised custom post types via shortcodes, along the lines of:

```
[myshortcode myshortcodegroup="groupname"]
```

This works just fine, however, I only want the custom content to be displayed via the use of a shortcode.

In other words, the content should **NOT** be accessible via `slug/post-name`.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code you use to register your post type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely a matter of configuring CPT registrations. [`register_post_type()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) has a lot of arguments related to visibility and access.

On top of my head to prevent CPT from having front-end links and queries you would want to set `publicly_queryable` to `false`.

Comment: Of course - forget that bit! In actual fact, all I needed to do was to remove 'public' => 'true' from the plugin registration defaults. Thanks.